# Grouping tasks in custom Gradle plugin?

Tags: plugins, gradle

I'm developing a custom Gradle plugin. How do I group different tasks under a group name.

Eg.

```
Tasks
- build
    - assemble
    - build
    - clean
    - ...
- myGroup
    - task1
    - task2
    - task3
    - ...
- ...
```

Comment: Yes. On the task list, it should be displayed like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution :

```
MyTask task = project.getTasks().create("task", MyTask.class);
task.setGroup("myGroup");
```

This will create a task named "task" under group "myGroup".

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
project.getTasks().create("task", MyTask.class).setGroup("myGroup");
```